# How to match any location from a given list of coordinates in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, geospatial

I am currently using MongoDB with node.js and Mongoose to perform geospatial searches.

I'm working with the following documents and collections:

- *waypoints* are documents that contain location and other metadata (just is there, not otherwise relevant for this question)
- *targets* collection contains `1...n` *waypoints*
- *sources* collection contains exactly `1` *waypoint*

Simple example of what these documents may look like:

```
// Target
{
  waypoints: [
    {
      loc: [61.24, 22.24],
      time: 0
    },
    {
      loc: [61.25, 22.24],
      time: 1
    },
    {
      loc: [61.26, 22.24],
      time: 2
    },
  ]
}

// Source
{
  waypoint: {
    loc: [61.24, 22.24],
    time: 0
  }
}
```

So my question is this:

**Given that we have a specific `target` document (like the one above), what is the easiest way to find all `source` documents near (within distance of MAX_DISTANCE) any of the given waypoints in the `target`?**

Matching for single waypoint is trivial:

```
Source.find({
  'from.loc': {
    $within: {
      $center: [target.waypoints[0].loc, MAX_DISTANCE],
      $uniqueDocs: true
    }
  }
})
```

However I'm struggling to find the solution of how to match any of the given waypoints. For instance the following query doesn't work:

```
Source.find({
  $or: [
    {
      'waypoint.loc': {
        $within: {
          $center: [target.waypoints[0].loc, MAX_DISTANCE],
          $uniqueDocs: true
        }
      }
    },
    {
      'waypoint.loc': {
        $within: {
          $center: [target.waypoints[1].loc, MAX_DISTANCE],
          $uniqueDocs: true
        }
      }
    },
    {
      'waypoint.loc': {
        $within: {
          $center: [target.waypoints[2].loc, MAX_DISTANCE],
          $uniqueDocs: true
        }
      }
    }
  ] 
})
```

Any ideas why this doesn't work and what would be the alternative?

All help is much appreciated!

P.S. I'm using MongoDB v2.0.5, Mongoose 2.7.4 & node v0.8.7

Comment: $any isn't a top level query operator. You're looking for $or

Comment: Thanks! $or doesn't work either -- I'll edit the question to reflect that.

Comment: If you post sample data and the shell compatible query you're trying I'll try and fix it for you. Your schema doesn't align with your queries ("from" != "waypoints" in Source)

Comment: Definitely, I'll try doing that. Just hold a sec!

Comment: @RemonvanVliet: http://www.coderemarks.com/review/l7JsUKIUULPeai0Y

Comment: Fixed the question - queries should now be valid. Also thanks for tipping about the shell. At least I now have a proper error (`"error: { "$err" : "$or may not contain 'special' query", "code" : 13291 }`). Wish I knew how to proceed from here!

Comment: This may be relevant too: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3984

Comment: @jsalonen: the ticket you linked is the limiting factor, here. The current version of MongoDB simply does not support this kind of query. Feel free to vote on the JIRA issue, as that determines how feature requests are prioritized for future development.

Comment: Seems like so :/ I'll reward all ideas on how to resolve this without hacky spagetti code bloat, because that's the only thing I can think of right now.

Comment: Can you give me a reason for the downvote? I will gladly improve.

Answer (score 2):

`$or` queries are implemented as separate queries internally anyway, so aside from a lack of elegance, something like the following works w/o too much bloat (with a little help from the [underscore](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#) library):

```
var nearSources = {}, count = target.waypoints.length;
target.waypoints.forEach(function (waypoint) {
  Source.find({
    'waypoint.loc': {
      $within: {
        $center: [waypoint.loc, MAX_DISTANCE],
        $uniqueDocs: true
      }
    }
  }, function (err, sources) {
    if (sources) {
      // Add the unique sources to the nearSources object by _id.
      sources.forEach(function (source) {
        nearSources[source._id] = source;
      });
    }
    if (--count === 0) {
      // Done!  Convert nearSources to an array of source docs.
      nearSources = _.values(nearSources);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Doesn't this potentially put really high load on the database? I mean what if I have like 1000 waypoints? Doesn't this basically make 1000 parallel queries to db? Do you know if there is any way to limit this number of parallel queries? I'm afraid this is the best solution so far, but I'm pretty sure this isn't the only answer!

Comment: What will happen is that Mongo will load the Source collection's `waypoint.loc` index into memory once and then each of those 1000 waypoint queries will occur against that.  So while it sounds like a lot of parallel queries I would expect it to perform well as it's almost all CPU.  Don't prematurely optimize by trying to limit that parallelism as that's likely wasted effort.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I preliminary tried this and it works as expected - I just was worried about whether this is a good idea performance-wise. You definitely deserve the bounty reward. Thanks!